# Microsoft TFS 2010 Build file modification date

Tags: tfs

We are building our sources and also keeping some of binaries/libs in TFS. Is it possible that the files are checked out with the last checkin date in TFS as "date modified"? It would make life easier.

Comment: Why not use [Labels](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181439(v=vs.100).aspx)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe that is possible, and it would be very bad if it were...

This is necessary for the Get to work properly: Imagine someone else checks in the files on Monday and you build your local code on Tuesday - when you then Get their changes, if they were date-stamped as "changed on Monday", then your PC would not see them as "newer" than your "Tuesday" build and your build would fail or be corrupted (in a number of possible ways - undefined behaviour).

The correct behaviour is that when you get "new" stuff onto your PC, it is seen as being "newer" than your build, so the next build updates everything and produces a valid/correct result. The next time you "Get", if nobody has checked in newer versions, the files will *not be touched* by TFS because nobody has checked in any changes, so their timestamps will not change, and there will be  no need to rebuild anything.

So in light of that... what is the problem? It works as it must work.

Comment: The problem is that, by comparing different tfs builds on the hard drive, you cannot determine whether some files changed or not. you can do it only by checking  the change date in TFS itself.

Comment: true. I'd recommend using TFS history rather than filestamps anyway. Or use a folder diff utility rather than trying to diff by eye?

Comment: All you probably need is to know if the binaries are different or not. if you have a large budget, Araxis Merge is awesome. If not, something like Beyond Compare is very good.